# how to find index of duplicated word in python

Tags: python, indexing

i write this code in python

```
import re

text = input('please enter text: ')
word = re.findall('\w+', text)
len_word = len(word)
word_pos = []

for i in range(len_word):
    if text.index(word[i]) in word_pos:
        prev_index = text.index(word[i]) + 1
        last_index = 0
        # print('index1: ' , last_index)
        text = text[prev_index:]
        # print('new_text: ' , new_text)
        word_pos.append(text.index(word[i]) + prev_index + last_index)
        last_index += prev_index
    else:
        word_pos.append(text.index(word[i]))

print(word_pos)
```

and the output of this input: a a  ,
is: [0 , 2] , and is correct  ,
but in this siguation: a a a  ,
answer is : [0 , 2 , 1]  ,
i want see : [0 , 2 , 4]  ,
and i want a dynamic code because i don't know when i get the duplacated word from input.
and if there is any solution i want get more duplicated word index
thanks

Comment: What is exact input?

Comment: Ow, my algorithmic complexity! Figure out a way to avoid that linear search.

Comment: Is it required that the input be a string?  If the string is `split()` into a list of words, the indices of replicates are different.  Example: `"a a a".split()` -> `['a', 'a', 'a']` -> `[0, 1, 2]` instead.  Also, repeated words is different than repeated letters.  What do you expect for `"foo bar aaaa aaa bar"`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
import re

text = input('please enter text: ')
words = re.findall('\w+', text)
word_pos = []
pos = 0 # this will help us track the word's position in the original text

for i in range(len(words)):
    word = words[i]
    pos += text[pos:].index(word) # we use the position of the last word to find the position of the current word
    if word in words[i+1:] or word in words[:i]: # we have a duplicate so we can append this position
        word_pos.append(pos) 
        print('{} found at {} in text'.format(word,pos))
    pos += 1
```

With input: `"a a a a"`, I get the result:

```
please enter text: a a a a a
a found at 0 in text
a found at 2 in text
a found at 4 in text
a found at 6 in text
a found at 8 in text
```

Comment: I just did, sorry for the delay. Why the downvote though?

Comment: name 'word_pos' is not defined

Comment: thanks its nice but 
one index is missing.
please enter text: a a a ,
a found at 0 in text ,
a found at 2 in text

Comment: @MeeladRavasani Can you try again with the current edit? It works for me.

Comment: @MeeladRavasani No problem. Feel free to accept the answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = input('please enter text: ')
print({word: [w.start() for w in re.finditer(word, text)] for word in text.split()})
```

input 1:

```
please enter text: a a a a

output:
{'a': [0, 2, 4, 6]}

input 2:
please enter text: Hello Arun Hello man

output:
{'Arun': [6], 'Hello': [0, 11], 'man': [17]}
```